# Sum column if its greater than or equal to a value in a corresponding column times a constant

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to sum the R column if the values in the I column are greater than the value in the corresponding R column times a constant.

Simply stated, the condition on each row is this: 
**Add R to the the sum if I is greater than or equal to R times a constant.**

The below is my best attempt at constructing a formula to accomplish this. I realize the syntax within the CONCAT is ignorantly written, but I hope it serves to get the intention across.

```
=SUMIF($I$2:$I$272,CONCAT(">=",R * AN36),$R$2:$R$272)*AN36
```

Comment: Welcome to Superuser,, plz [edit] your post & share some sample data with us along with the expected output,, help us to fix it! Meanwhile U try this `=SUMIF($I$2:$I$272,">="&RAN*AN36,$R$2:$R$272)*AN36`,, I guess the R is a name given to cell, but remember Excel doesn't accepts so that I've used RAN,, which is editable!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it seems that multiplying a range by a constant in the criteria of SUMIF results in an array instead of a single number. See the array starting on U5 and spilling downward.

The way I understand this, you have your constant in cell AN36. To make the screenshot narrower, I have mine in V3. I believe you have three options.

[image]

**Option 1**

Column S:

```
=I2>R2*$V$2
```

Cell X2:

```
=SUMIF($S$2:$S$11,TRUE,$R$2:$R$11)
```

You could calculate the whether the condition is met for each row (as in column S) then use the formula displayed in cell Y2 that I've used in cell X2. This is simple and lets you see what's going on.

**Option 2**

Cell X10:

```
=SUM(IF($I$2:$I$11>$R$2:$R$11*$V$2,$R$2:$R$11,0))
```

If you have a recent version of Excel 365, you can use dynamic arrays in the IF function, and use the formula displayed in cell Y10, which I've used in X10. This is my preferred option as it doesn't require the helper column S.

**Option 3**

Cell X14:

```
{=SUM(IF($I$2:$I$11>$R$2:$R$11*$V$2,$R$2:$R$11,0))}
```

If you have an earlier version of Excel, you can still achieve the same result as option 2 but you need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> at the end of typing the function instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will mean the formula is treated as an array formula and will return a single value.

Note that I have not included the multiplication of the returned value by the constant (at the end of your function) as this was not in your description of the desired result. So please adjust as necessary.